# Contact PHP form - not receiving mail (GMAIL)

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap, email, contacts

Ive been trying to get my contact form working, but i'm not receiving any emails in my gmail folders (including spam and trash. and also can't track anything through my host).

I've been following this tutorial: http://bootstrapious.com/p/how-to-build-a-working-bootstrap-contact-form

Need some serious help as i've tried everything!

```
<?php


$from = $_POST['email'];
$sendTo = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$subject = 'New message from contact form';
$fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'surname' => 'Surname', 'email' =>     'Email',  'phone' => 'Phone', 'message' => 'Message');

 // array variable name => Text to appear in email

$okMessage = 'Contact form succesfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back     to you soon!';
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';

// let's do the sending

try
{
$emailText = "You have new message from contact     form\n=============================\n";

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

    if (isset($fields[$key])) {
        $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
    }
 }

  mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, "From: " . $from);

  $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
$responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&     strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
$encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo $encoded;
}
else {
echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

THE HTML FORM

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php" role="form">

<div class="messages"></div>

  <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
              <label>First name*</label>
              <input type="text" id="form-name" name="name" class="form-     control" placeholder="Please enter your firstname *" required="required">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
              <label>Last name*</label>
              <input type="text" name="surname" id="form-surname"     class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your firstname *"     required="required">
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <label>Email*</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="form-email"  class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your firstname *"  required="required">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <label>Phone</label>
                <input type="tel" name="phone" id="form-phone" class="form- control" placeholder="Please enter your phone">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="comment">Message*</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="7" name="message" id="form-message" default="Type us a message" required="required"></textarea>
    </div>    

    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Join mailing list</label>
    </div>  
    <input type="submit" class="btm btn-success btn-send" value="Send message">
    <p class="text-muted"><strong>*</strong> These fields are required.</p>
 </form>
```

Comment: have you got any error message?

Comment: Does your host support php mail() ?

Comment: No error message as far as i can tell when submitting

Comment: Are you testing on localhost?

Comment: contacted my host and mail needs to be authenticated ? how to achieve this

Comment: May be Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36910789/form-to-email-xampp-php-javascript-mac-os/36910887#36910887

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As many servers don't allow you to send emails in the name of someone whom is not registered, you should create an email on your server that's only for sending you the emails that your users write once they fill the contact form, then you should use a class like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) to send the email for you.

A simple example showing how to use PHPMailer would be:

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.yourserver.here';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@userserver.here';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'password';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('user@userserver.here', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('your@email.here', 'You');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addReplyTo('theuser@email.here', 'User that submitted form');

$mail->Subject = 'Subject here';
$mail->Body    = 'Write here your message';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

The example is taken from the link I've told you above.

Comment: After creating the email account uploading the phpmailer files and inputting the value in the php code above how would i go about testing it?

Comment: You can put this code inside a function and call the function once you press the submit button

Answer (score 1):

You don't have Mail Delivery error?

Try send email from know host in:

```
$from = $_POST['email']; (like youremail@gmail.com)
```

Gmail checks DKIM (posted by) and SPF (signed by) record in DNS server to email host. If email host don't have a DKIM record, email may be not supplied.

More (gmail):

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/180707?hl=en

More (How To Install and Configure DKIM):

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-dkim-with-postfix-on-debian-wheezy

Comment: i'm using shared hosting, apparently all mail needs to be authenticated?

Comment: To gmail, you must authenticated domain for emails in DNS TXT record.